# AVPlayer and networkActivityIndicatorVisible

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, avplayer

since iOS 7 the networkActivityIndicator is displayed automatically by the system when remote audio is streamed and played (not in the simulator, but on the device).

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://streams.ffh.de/radioffh/mp3/hqlivestream.m3u";
AVPlayer *radioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
[radioPlayer play];
```

Is there a way to prevent the display of the networkActivityIndicator?

Comment: This is still an issue. Have you found a solution?